# Не получается импортировать библиотеку

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пишу на Django, хочу импортировать views в файл urls.

```py
from django.urls import path

from .views import *
# import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='home'),
]
```

Этот не выкидывает ошибку, но если пытаюсь импортировать так:

```py
from django.urls import path

# from .views import *
import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
]
```

Ты python кидает ошибку: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'`
Совершенно не понимаю в чем может быть проблема.[image: Структура проекта]

UPD:

Нашел решение сразу как написал вопрос). Вот так все работает.

```py
from django.urls import path

# from .views import *
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
]
```

Осталось понять почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что мы запускаем сервер через manage.py. У нас рабочая директория та, где расположен manage.py.
Импорт ищет по путям из sys.path. А там нет директории, в которой находится views.py.

Поэтому и используются импорты с точкой. Это относительные импорты. Они указывают, что модуль надо искать в той же директории, в которой находится текущий модуль, откуда этот импорт и производится. А две точки говорят, что надо искать на уровень выше.